# How to get text out of Word Document using C# open-xml SDK in json like format?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk, text-extraction

I'm trying to extract all the text from a word document using C# open-xml SDK, and I want to store the style attributes and innerText data from each of the paragraphs and then for each of the runs inside a paragraph (and eventually the same thing for the tables too).

```
{
    "paragraphs": 
    [
        {
            "innerText": "",
            "runs": [
                {
                    "runProperties": {}, 
                    "innerText": ""
                }
            ],
            "paragraphProperties": {}
        }
    ],
    "tables":
    [
        {
​
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the desired structure.

I'm from python background where doing this using python dict would've been easy since there's no strict type for value of the key in a dict. But I've got little to no idea on how to approach this in C#.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = @"<path to file>";
​
            using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
            {
                IEnumerable<Paragraph> paragraphList = myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements().Where(c => c is Paragraph).Cast<Paragraph>();
                foreach (Paragraph p in paragraphList)
                {
                    string paragraphInnerText = p.InnerText;
                    IEnumerable<Run> runList = p.ChildElements.Where(c => c is Run).Cast<Run>();
                    foreach (Run r in runList)
                    {
                        string runInnerText = r.InnerText;
                        IEnumerable<RunProperties> runProperties = r.ChildElements.Where(c => c is RunProperties).Cast<RunProperties>();
                        Console.WriteLine("Getting Run Data.");
                    }
                    IEnumerable<ParagraphProperties> paragraphPropertiesList = p.ChildElements.Where(r => r is ParagraphProperties).Cast<ParagraphProperties>();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("All done. Press a key.");
        }
```

This is the code I've come up with so far, with some help.

Any ideas on how can I store this in the json format, or how should I go about it?
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

Option A, convert all document using source xml with SerializeXmlNode ([JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.OuterXml);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

Option B, create anonymus type for all paragraph and run's:

```
IEnumerable<Paragraph> paragraphList = myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements().OfType<Paragraph>();
var proj = paragraphList.Select(p => p.ChildElements.OfType<Run>().Select(r => new
{
    r.InnerText,
    runProperties = r.ChildElements.OfType<RunProperties>().FirstOrDefault()?.Select(rp => new { rp.GetType().Name, Val = rp.GetAttributes().FirstOrDefault().Value })
}));
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(proj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```